Integrating OAuth2 with Spring Security while keeping custom user object
We are transitioning our Spring Security application from username/password authentication to OAuth2. We've successfully added OAuth2 login to our security chain, but we're facing issues with the user object in the security context.
Here's our current setup:
User Object:
public class CustomUser implements UserDetails {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private Set<CustomRole> roles;
    // Many more fields, getters, setters, etc.
}

public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            return getUserByLoginname(username);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("");
        }
    }

    public CustomUser getUserByLoginname(String identifier) throws NotFoundException {
        // Load User from database
    }
}

Then in a lot of places we use the following snipped to retrive the logged in user:
@GetMapping(value = "/XXX")
public void XXX() {
    CustomUser loggedInUser = (CustomUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
// ... 
}

Now we are looking to integrate OAuth2 while retaining our CustomUser model. Our goal is to use OAuth2 solely for authentication purposes and not to retrieve any authorities or roles from the OAuth flow. Instead, we want to maintain and manage user roles within our own database. To achieve this, I have incorporated the oauth2Login into the security configuration as follows:
@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http, ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository)
        throws Exception {
    http
        .cors(c -> corsConfigurationSource())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/XXX"),
                        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/XXXXX"))
                    .permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated())

            .oauth2Login(o -> o.authorizationEndpoint(end -> end
                    .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository))))

            .logout(l -> l.logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutsite").permitAll())

            .sessionManagement(management -> management.maximumSessions(-1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()))
            .headers(headers -> headers.referrerPolicy(policy -> policy.policy(ReferrerPolicy.NO_REFERRER)))
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
    return http.build();
}

This also works, the authentication is succsessful. But now we have the problem that in the security context we have a DefaultOidcUser instead of our customUser object.
I considered adding a filter after the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to replace the User object in the SecurityContext with our custom object. However, this approach feels somewhat dirty.
I thought of adding a filter after the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which replaces the Userobject in the SecurityContext with a new one. But this seems a little bit dirty. I feel like there has to be a better way. But all the methods I've tried so far, such as using OAuthUserService or OidcUserService still result in an OAuth object of some sort.
My question is: How can I use OAuth only for authentication and then load only my CustomUser object into the security context, while ignoring any grants and authorities from OAuth?

"Our goal is to use OAuth2 solely for authentication purposes and not to retrieve any authorities or roles from the OAuth flow". You'd better use the authorization server as a "user-service" and have it manage user roles. Apps with oauth2Login  are OAuth2 clients (which need protection against CSRF, so you'd better re-activate that). It is designed to use the access token it gets during authorization code flow to send requests to resource servers. These resource servers will need roles in claims to decide if it should permit a request...

if you read the spring security documentation this is exact what the GrantedAuthoritiesMapper is to be used for. It is documented here in the docs.
And here is the code example from the docs:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                    .userAuthoritiesMapper(this.userAuthoritiesMapper())
                    ...
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                if (OidcUserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority)authority;

                    OidcIdToken idToken = oidcUserAuthority.getIdToken();
                    OidcUserInfo userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();

                    // Map the claims found in idToken and/or userInfo
                    // to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities

                } else if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority)authority;

                    Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

                    // Map the attributes found in userAttributes
                    // to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities

                }
            });

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
}

In the provided code example from the docs, they manually extract the authorities from the JWT, etc and return a map with the new GrantedAuthorities, but in your case i believe you would instead call your database and fetch the needed ahtorities (roles) and construct a map with the authorities you need and return it.

I don't think that this does what i want, as it does not load a different user object into the security context. It only replaces the authorities which are stored in the oAuth User object and then stores that in the security context

You write Our goal is to use OAuth2 solely for authentication purposes and not to retrieve any authorities or roles from the OAuth flow. Instead, we want to maintain and manage user roles within our own database. And it does not mention that you want to change out the entire Authentication object. I will leave this answer for future readers. Good luck

Ah, I understand the confusion. Maybe to make it clearer how I imagine it should work:
1.) User comes onto our site and gets forwarded to the OAuth Login
2.) User completes the Login successfully
3.) We extract the email address of the successful oAuth Object
4.) Based on this email we load our custom principal into the security context
At the moment I have a working solution based on a filter. Basically, I created a security filter at the end of the chain that checks if the principal in the context is of type oAuth and if so, I load our custom object and store it in the context.
